# Hiding and unhiding spreadsheet rows using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am completely new in writing scripts and I have just learned about Google Script Editor. I am currently trying to write one to automatically hide rows based on values on my spreadsheet. I managed to do it looking at various websites but I also want to unhide the rows if the value happens to change.

I'm new to this so I have copied the script I currently have but I think I have a problem in line 12 (the 'else' part).

```
   function onEdit() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
     var LastRow = Sheet.getLastRow();
     for( i=1 ; i<=LastRow ; i++) { // i <= lastrow
       var status = Sheet.getRange("A"+i).getValue(); // Change A to 
the completed column
       if (status == 0) {                                          //     status == 0
         Sheet.hideRows(i);
       else {
           Sheet.unhideRows(i);
              }
       }
     }
   }
```

I would kindly like someone to help me with writing the correct code at the end to be able to unhide rows that were previously hidden based on values. I happen to work with data that's constantly changing and hiding/unhiding rows is very important to me. Thank you

Comment: How would the status change from 0 to something else, if the rows were hidden?

Answer (score 3):

- You need to close the `if` block before starting the `else` clause. If you format your code cleanly, it's easier to notice such syntax errors.
- The `Sheet` class does not have an `unhideRows()` method.

---

There are some important differences to note between the methods used for hiding vs. unhiding rows.

For hiding, these methods are provided:

- [`hideRow(row)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowrow)
- [`hideRows(rowIndex)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hiderowsrowindex)
- [`hideRows(rowIndex, numRows)`](http://hideRows(rowIndex,%20numRows))

For unhiding, a single method is provided:

- [`unhideRow(row)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#unhiderowrow).

As mentioned above, there are no unhide equivalents to the `hideRows()` methods.

`hideRow(row)` and `unhideRow(row)` both take a [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object as an argument, as opposed to a row number.

Therefore you need to store the `Range` object returned from the `getRange()` method, so you can provide it as an argument when you call `hideRows()`.

---

Here's a cleaned up and corrected version:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var LastRow = Sheet.getLastRow();
  for (i = 1; i <= LastRow; i++) {
    var statusRange = Sheet.getRange("A" + i);
    if (statusRange.getValue() == 0) {
      Sheet.hideRows(i);
    } else {
      Sheet.unhideRow(statusRange);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Mohdio Another thing worth noting is that calling `getValue()` in a loop is extremely slow and it's best practice to [batch up operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use-batch-operations): to use `getValues()` and if possible, even batch up row hiding using `hideRows()`